# Use gganimate to display calculation of tweened data

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I would like to use **gganimate** to:

- Graph two separate curved lines with `geom_path`
- Call a function that performs a calculation with the data from those lines and returns a single coordinate (x, y)
- Plot that coordinate as a `geom_point`
- Move the lines around, with the `geom_point` updating as the lines move

This is simple if the movement is such that the single (x, y) coordinate moves linearly (just calculate it at each stage ahead of time and then animate it, it will move linearly from each stage to the next), but if it's not I'm not sure what to do. If I call a function within `aes()`, which seems like the natural solution, it seems to calculate it once at the beginning and then not update it as the lines move.

Here is an example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

# A function to find the x and y coordinate of the minimum y value of either set
min_of_both <- function(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  cm <- bind_rows(tibble(x = x1, y = y1),
                  tibble(x = x2, y = y2))

  return(list(x = cm[which(cm$y == min(cm$y)),]$x,
              y = min(cm$y)))
}

# Create two parabola paths, curve A which moves downwards from t = 1 to t = 2
curveA <- tibble(xA = -50:50/10, yA = 5+(-50:50/10)^2, t = 1) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(xA = -50:50/10, yA = -10 + (-50:50/10)^2, t = 2))
# And curve B which is static in both time 1 and 2
curveB <- tibble(xB = -50:50/10, yB = 1 + (-30:70/10)^2)

data <- curveB %>%
  bind_rows(curveB) %>%
  bind_cols(curveA)

# Plot Curve A
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = xA, y = yA)) + 
  geom_path(color = 'red') +
  # And Curve B
  geom_path(aes(x=xB,y=yB), color = 'blue')+
  # Then plot a single point that uses both curves as input
  # Note I also get problems if trying to run the function through data= instead of mapping=
  # or if I define two separate functions, one for x and one for y, so as to avoid $
  geom_point(aes(
    x = min_of_both(xA,yA,xB,yB)$x, 
    y = min_of_both(xA,yA,xB,yB)$y), 
    size = 3,
    color = 'black') +
  theme_minimal()+
  transition_states(t)+
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')
animate(p)
```

This results in (not sure if the animation will play on StackOverflow but the parabola does indeed move):

[image: Animation of two parabolas]

The black dot is intended to mark the lowest y-coordinate on either parabola at each moment, but instead it marks the lowest y-coordinate on either parabola at any point in the animation (at the end).

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Sorry had tried something there but I'd clearly misunderstood your point. Will correct and repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of head-scratching I think I've understood your point and have found one solution. The best way forward might be to manually `tween` the paths and calculate the min values using your function whilst grouping by `.frame` before plotting:

```r
# Same curve setup, but labelling points for grouping later
curveA <- tibble(xA = -50:50/10, 
                 yA = 5+(-50:50/10)^2, 
                 point = 1:101,
                 t = 1) %>%
  bind_rows(tibble(xA = -50:50/10, 
                   yA = -10 + (-50:50/10)^2,
                   point = 1:101,
                   t = 2))

curveB <- tibble(xB = -50:50/10, 
                 yB = 1 + (-30:70/10)^2,
                 point = 1:101,
                 t = 1)


A_frames <-  curveA %>%
  tween_along(ease = 'sine-in-out', 100, along = t, id = point) %>% 
  filter(.phase == "transition") %>% 
  select(xA, yA, point, .frame) %>% 
  arrange(.frame, point)  # arrange by point needed to keep in order

B_frames <-  curveB %>%
  bind_rows(curveB %>% mutate(t = 2)) %>% 
  tween_along(ease = 'sine-in-out', 100, along = t, id = point) %>% 
  filter(.phase == "transition") %>% 
  select(xB, yB, point, .frame) %>%
  arrange(.frame, point)


data <- A_frames %>%
  left_join(B_frames, by = c(".frame", "point")) %>% 
  group_by(.frame) %>% 
  mutate(xmin = min_of_both(xA,yA,xB,yB)$x,
         ymin = min_of_both(xA,yA,xB,yB)$y)

# Plot Curve A
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = xA, y = yA)) + 
  geom_path(color = 'red') +
  # And Curve B
  geom_path(aes(x=xB,y=yB), color = 'blue')+
  # Then plot a single point that uses both curves as input
  # Note I also get problems if trying to run the function through data= instead of mapping=
  # or if I define two separate functions, one for x and one for y, so as to avoid $
  geom_point(aes(xmin, ymin), 
             size = 3,
             color = 'black') +
  theme_minimal()+
  transition_states(.frame)+
  ease_aes('sine-in-out')

animate(p, fps = 24)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh that absolutely works. Don't know why I didn't think of it!